# Java MP3Player by using Javazoom play and pause

Tags: java, mp3, audio-player

I'm making a simple MP3Player in Java. I have managed to play a .mp3 file but when I start playing the whole program freezes and I can't click any buttons in the program. I need help making the pause button, or any other button work after I start playing. This is my code:

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.net.URL;
    import javazoom.jl.player.advanced.AdvancedPlayer;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class MP3Player extends JFrame{

    public MP3Player(){
        JPanel jpBottom = new JPanel();
        JButton btnPlay = new JButton("Play");
        JButton btnPause = new JButton("Pause");

        jpBottom.add(btnPause);
        jpBottom.add(btnPlay);

        Container cp = this.getContentPane();
        BorderLayout bl = new BorderLayout();
        cp.setLayout(bl);
        cp.add(jpBottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        btnPlay.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        Play("file:///C://a.mp3");
                    }
                }
        );

        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setSize(250, 100);
        this.setTitle("MP3 Player");
        this.setLocation(100, 100);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void Play(String path){
        try{
            URL url = new URL(path);
            InputStream in = url.openStream();
            //Player pl = new Player(in);
            //pl.play();
            AdvancedPlayer pl = new AdvancedPlayer(in);

            pl.getPlayBackListener();
            pl.play();             
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Feil: "+e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MP3Player n = new MP3Player();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `Play()` method in a separate thread and also have a good understanging of [Multithreding in Swing](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Threads/swing/). At least you should read about [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

Answer (score 1):

> I need help making the pause button, ..

The method to pause the player is [`stop()`](http://org.ntnu.no/tdt4100_600/javadoc/javazoom/jl/player/advanced/AdvancedPlayer.html#stop%28%29).  But that code creates the `AdvancedPlayer` local to a method.  Instead, the class needs to declare an `AdvancedPlayer` attribute and reference that class attribute in the `actionPerformed()` method.